# MDX - Grand total missing when filtering

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

I've been working on an ExcelDNA C# xll that allows users to enter simple words (under guidance) and I construct the elaborate MDX for them to query against a remote ActivePivot cube.

During testing I've ntoticed that when filtering, the grand total disappears (presumably it's joining tuples together). How do I still get a grand total? Do I need to use SCOPE or create a calculated member?

Thanks to more advanced MDX people:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Notional.SUM]
     ,[Measures].[Notional.SHORT]
     ,[Measures].[Notional.LONG]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize
    (
      Filter
      (
        (
          [CDR].[CDR].MEMBERS
         ,[Book].[Book].MEMBERS
        )
       ,
        Left([Book].[Book].CurrentMember.MemberValue,2) = "22"
      )
     ,POST
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [TraderCube]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Date].[2020-01-24];
```

Comment: So you are after an addition of a Total row?

Comment: Hi. yes, by default I get a grand total row on normal queries but when I filter this total row disappears (i'm guessing you get back a joined set of the tuples you wanted) and do I have to specify an aggregation / sum calculated total row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is something similar against AdvWrks cube:

```
WITH 

  //>>inside the WITH clause we have moved the set
  SET [FilteredSet] AS 
    {
      Filter
      (
        [Reseller].[Reseller Type].[Business Type].MEMBERS
       ,
          Left([Reseller].[Reseller Type].CurrentMember.MemberValue,2) = "sp"
        OR 
          Left([Reseller].[Reseller Type].CurrentMember.MemberValue,2) = "VA"
      )
    } 

  //>>next we create a custom member that is the sum of the filtered set 
  MEMBER [Reseller].[Reseller Type].[All Visible Resellers] AS 
    Aggregate([FilteredSet]) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 

    //>> inside these curly brackets we declare a set that is the filtered set and the Total member
    { 
      [FilteredSet]
     ,[Reseller].[Reseller Type].[All Visible Resellers]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2013];
```

The results of the above is the following:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks alot for this; it makes sense. I will try it today. It seems funny to me, as I learn more and more MDX, that it seems incredibly powerful but sometimes you have to do stuff like this to get a total (yet it seems to be totalling most of the time :) ).

Comment: I posted on an MS forum too. Someone replied with "The (All, All) tuple gets filtered out because its membervalue for Book doesn't start with 22. Move your filtering to Where or to a subselect" which falls inline with your reply too.